# Magento 2.2.6 exception

Tags: magento2

Getting below execption. Any clue please?

> {"0":"Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array
>   given in
>   /chroot/home/a353f659/website.com/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Asset/Minification.php
>   on line 146","1":"#0 [internal function]:
>   Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(2, 'explode()
>   expec...', '/chroot/home/a3...', 146, Array)\n#1
>   /chroot/home/a353f659/website.com/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Asset/Minification.php(146):
>   explode('\n', Array)\n#2
>   /chroot/home/a353f659/website.com/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Asset/Minification.php(129):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Minification->getExcludes('css')\n#3
>   /chroot/home/a353f659/website.com/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Asset/Minification.php(87):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Minification->isExcluded('frontend/Infort...')\n#4
>   /chroot/home/a353f659/website.com/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Asset/File.php(115):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Minification->addMinifiedSign('frontend/Infort...')\n#5
>   /chroot/home/a353f659/website.com/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Asset/File.php(87):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Asset\File->getPath()\n#6
>   /chroot/home/a353f659/website.com/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config/Renderer.php(375):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Asset\File->getUrl()\n#7
>   /chroot/home/a353f659/website.com/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config/Renderer.php(261):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config\Renderer->renderAssetHtml(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Asset\PropertyGroup))\n#8
>   /chroot/home/a353f659/website.com/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config/Renderer.php(248):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config\Renderer->renderAssetGroup(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Asset\PropertyGroup))\n#9
>   /chroot/home/a353f659/website.com/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config\Renderer->renderAssets(Array)\n#10
>   /chroot/home/a353f659/website.com/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config\Renderer\Interceptor->___callParent('renderAssets',
>   Array)\n#11
>   /chroot/home/a353f659/website.com/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config\Renderer\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Array)\n#12
>   /chroot/home/a353f659/website.com/html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Page/Config/Renderer/Interceptor.php(26):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config\Renderer\Interceptor->___callPlugins('renderAssets',
>   Array, Array)\n#13
>   /chroot/home/a353f659/website.com/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config/Renderer.php(101):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config\Renderer\Interceptor->renderAssets(Array)\n#14
>   /chroot/home/a353f659/website.com/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Page.php(249):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config\Renderer->renderHeadContent()\n#15
>   /chroot/home/a353f659/website.com/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Layout.php(170):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page->render(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))\n#16
>   /chroot/home/a353f659/website.com/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))\n#17
>   /chroot/home/a353f659/website.com/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callParent('renderResult',
>   Array)\n#18
>   /chroot/home/a353f659/website.com/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))\n#19
>   /chroot/home/a353f659/website.com/html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Result/Page/Interceptor.php(26):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callPlugins('renderResult',
>   Array, Array)\n#20
>   /chroot/home/a353f659/website.com/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(139):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))\n#21
>   /chroot/home/a353f659/website.com/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(257):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()\n#22
>   /chroot/home/a353f659/website.com/html/index.php(47):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))\n#23
>   {main}","url":"/","script_name":"/index.php"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try running the following commands from your www / http directory in SSH

rm -rf var/generation var/di

php-7.0 bin/magento setup:di:compile

This will force any dependency injections to be deleted and regenerated. Hope this helps.

Comment: Awesome. It works